# latex3: error when including amsmath

Tags: macros, amsmath, latex3

The following code still renders correctly but throws an error ('Missing } inserted') when including amsmath:

```
\cs_new:Npn \putInEnvironment:nnn #1 #2 #3
{
    \if_bool:N #2
        \tl_put_left:Nn  #1 {#3\c_group_begin_token}
        \tl_put_right:Nn #1 {\c_group_end_token}
    \fi:
}
```

used, e.g., for

```
\putInEnvironment:nnn {\l_my_symbol_tl}{\l_my_corrected_bool}{\hat}
\putInEnvironment:nnn {\l_my_symbol_tl}{\l_my_dot_bool}{\dot}
```

as part of a larger macro.
Other environments, e.g., \underline, still work.
Can somebody explain to me how I can fix this? Thanks!

EDIT:
Thanks for the quick response, to clarify:

- The intention was to build up a symbol using a lot of possible modifies (via key-value), which leads to nesting of quite some \cmd{< symbol >}
- my misunderstanding was that I thought \cmd{< symbol >} == \cmd\group_begin< symbol >\group_end, which was what the function did, nest, what I erroneously called environments
- funny enough, without including amsmath my function did what I intended

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Note that `\hat\c_group_begin_token x\c_group_end_token` will take `\c_group_begin_token` as the argument to `\hat`. This would be the same as `\hat\bgroup x\egroup` that *doesn't* work; why `\underline\bgroup x\egroup` works is another story. What's your purpose?

Comment: it is not clear what you want to do here and the terminology you are using is confusing, `\underline`, `\dot` etc are not environments. what do you intend this to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\cs_new_protected:Npn \behe_putInEnvironment:NNN #1 #2 #3
 {
  \bool_if:NT #2
   {
    \tl_set:Nx #1 { \exp_not:N #3 { \exp_not:V #1 } }
   }
 }

\behe_putInEnvironment:NNN \l_my_symbol_tl \l_my_corrected_bool \hat
\behe_putInEnvironment:NNN \l_my_symbol_tl \l_my_dot_bool       \dot
```

Altough as david and egreg say, it's not clear what you intend. Other things:

- `\putInEnvironment:nnn` is weird surrounded with the style of `\behe_put_in_environment:`; plus
- `\hat` and `\underline` are not “environments”; plus
- `:nnn` should be `:NNN` since the three arguments are single token; plus
- I used `_protected` since the command is not expandable; plus
- I used `\bool_if:NT` rather than the *plainer* `\if_bool:N`.